# Correct approach to creating API endpoints

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an API in Django Rest Framework and i'm thinking about best approach to provide actions like adding a post to user reading list. Firstly i've done it by GET request, because it was looking most natural and url for example looks like `/api/posts/{id}/add_to_reading_list/`. Now i recognized that GET should be used only to retrieve data so i've changed it to POST method and now url is looking like `/api/posts/add_to_reading_list/`. The first thing is that i needed to create new serializer specially to handle this action which accepts only id field, because this endpoint should accept only already created posts. Is it how it should be done? I was thinking about sending whole post object in POST method, but doesn't it a waste of bandwidth when i need only id? It will prevent me of creating a new serializer for this specific case, but i don't think that it is a correct approach.

Comment: Why don't you still send the id in the url? Don't see why you can't use `/api/posts/{id}/add_to_reading_list/` with a POST request.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Wow, i didn't know that it is possible. So should i simply send id in url without any POST data? I will get a try.